# typescript error TS2304: Cannot find name AsyncIterator even with esnext

Tags: typescript, graphql

I get the following error:

```
node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(36,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'.
node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(47,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'.
node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(75,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterable'.
3:01:18 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

Even with adding **esnext** to tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "esnext.asynciterable"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: It works for me.  How are you building?  Just `tsc -w`?  Are you sure your `tsconfig.json` file is being used?  If you add an invalid `lib` value such as `"esnext.invalid"`, do you get an error?

Comment: yes, tsc -w. I just restarted my laptop and now it is working!! That's very weird, I don't see why before it was not working...

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. I have fixed updating project dependencies to the last version:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
```

Versions previously were these:

```
 body-parser        ^1.18.1  →   ^1.19.0 
 express            ^4.15.4  →   ^4.17.1 
 reflect-metadata   ^0.1.10  →   ^0.1.13 
 @types/node       ^8.10.61  →  ^14.0.23 
 ts-node              3.3.0  →    8.10.2 
 typescript        3.3.3333  →     3.9.6
```